# Запятая перед "и оттого"

Tags: пунктуация

*Тот вечер был любопытен для девочки только одним: она узнала, что когда папа спит, глаза его не закрываются полностью **(,) и оттого** создается впечатление, что добрая родительская слежка не имеет конца.*

Здесь у нас сложноподчиненное предложение, «глаза его не закрываются полностью» и «оттого создается впечатление» – придаточные части, не требующие разделения запятой. Верно? Или я что-то не так понимаю. Помогите, пожалуйста, избавиться от сомнений.

Comment: А меня заинтересовало, почему тут нет запятой перед словом "когда". Ведь у него нет последующего соотносительного слова "тогда" или "то".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если предложения *«глаза его не закрываются полностью»* и *«оттого создается впечатление»* являются однородными придаточными, относясь к глаголу *"узнала"* и отвечая на вопрос *что?*, то запятая перед И ОТТОГО не нужна:

***Тот вечер был любопытен для девочки только одним: она узнала, что, когда папа спит, глаза его не закрываются полностью и [что] оттого создается впечатление, что добрая родительская слежка не имеет конца.***

Ср.: ***Когда папа спит, глаза его не закрываются полностью, и оттого создается впечатление, что добрая родительская слежка не имеет конца.*** - Здесь совсем другая история: придаточное *"когда папа спит"* относится к главному *"глаза его не закрываются полностью"*, далее присоединяется с помощью союза И ещё одно сложное предложение "*оттого (=по этой причине) создается впечатление, что добрая родительская слежка не имеет конца*".

На стыке союзов *что, когда* нужно поставить запятую, так как нет продолжения второго союза.

Comment: Дети не воспринимают слежку как нечто доброе, это их напрягает и раздражает, поэтому это не то, что узнала девочка, а комментарий со стороны, и запятая нужна.

Comment: Прекрасно понимаю Ваши сомнения, ибо  тоже так думала. Всё не так просто, на мой взгляд. Здесь ещё двоеточие играет свою роль и фраза "только одним". Это одно - "узнала". Если запятую поставить, то вечер любопытен уже не "только одним": во-первых, тем, что она "узнала"; во-вторых, тем, что впечатление создаётся. Сложно всё.

Comment: Нет, с запятой уже будет не то, что узнала, а комментарий рассказчика (присоединение). Там много проблем. Вечер не может быть любопытным, нет такого в словарях. Надо так: *в тот вечер любопытным было только одно*. *Это одно - "узнала"* — а здесь ещё одна проблема. Любопытно не то, что она узнала (совершила это действие), а сам факт, который узнала. То есть "она узнала, что" немного нарушает структуру. В плане грамматики в идеале надо так: *только одним: [а именно] тем, что когда...*